# Operaciones con Listas utilizando Prolog

Tags: prolog

soy nueva en Prolog y me dejaron una serie de ejercicios, en el cual uno en particular no logro resolver del todo! El ejercicio dice: "Dado dos listas de elementos,proporcionar una lista que contenga las parejas formadas por los elementos que correspondan". Como tal utilice concatenación en las listas pero solo me imprime los valores de las listas:

Conc([],L,L).
conc([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-
    conc(L1,L2,L3).

Comment: Bienvenida a stackoverflow, pásate por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para comprender el funcionamiento del sitio y mira [cómo hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
unir([],L,L).
unir([X|L1],L2,[X|L3]):-unir(L1,L2,L3).
```

ejecutas:

```
unir([1,2,3],[4,5,6],R).
```

Comment: Podrías añadir una explicación de tu código por favor?

Answer (score -1):

Estimada Esperanza:
Hola. Según el enunciado del problema, me parece que lo que te están pidiendo es formar pares que se correspondan por su posición en la lista. Por ejemplo:

?-concatenar_pares( [ t,d,z,s], [p,b,v,f], Listadepares).
Listadepares = [[t,p][d,b][z,v][s,f]].

Dime si es así, para poder ayudarte gustoso.
Jorge Fuentes